# Which template should I use for theos nic.pl

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak, theos, tweak, myo

I am trying to make a tweak that allows a myo to interface with my iDevice.

```
[1.] iphone/application
[2.] iphone/library
[3.] iphone/preference_bundle
[4.] iphone/tool
[5.] iphone/tweak
```

I originally picked the 'tweak' option but I am starting to think it might be better to try something else? Ideally, i'd like to write the code that translates the myo data into tangible swipes that will inject the movement into other apps. This is my first attempt at Jailbroken development so any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You want option 5, tweak. I suggest you look at the [wiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Main_Page) for some help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your project to be injected into other applications, then you want a tweak.

Each project type has a specific purpose:

- application: A standard application, like you'd install from the App Store, launched from the home screen (but not sandboxed by default)
- library: A library which contains some reusable functionality for use in other projects
- preference_bundle: A settings bundle which will be loaded into Settings.app
- tool: A program run from the command line
- tweak: A library to be injected into other software by Substrate